# Qt - How to execute this command?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I'm trying to accept automatically the host key when connecting to a server using this command

```
QString cmd = QString("echo y | plink.exe -ssh %1 -i root.ppk -l root exit").arg(strSensorAddress)
```

When I launch it from `cmd.exe` in Windows it is working.

I have tried to do it in Qt like this but it doesn't work :

```
QString cmd = QString("plink.exe -ssh %1 -i root.ppk -l root exit").arg(strSensorAddress);

process1.setStandardOutputProcess(&process2);

process1.start("echo y");
process2.start(cmd);
process2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
```

And like this :

```
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "plink.exe" << "-ssh" << strSensorAddress << "-i" << "root.ppk" << "-l" << "root" << "exit";

process1.setStandardOutputProcess(&process2);
process1.start("echo y");
process2.start("cmd.exe", arguments);
process2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
```

Comment: You need to call `setProcessChannelMode` *before* you call `start`.

Comment: This is cryptographically catastrophic.  See http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/accept-host-keys.html for why this is a really bad idea in general.  (It's OK if you are just running ssh as an internal remote execution protocol, and don't care about the security at all.)

Comment: Might as well use telnet if you wish to do that...